# How do I use DISTINCT inside a MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, distinct

I want to list the incoming data once but not work

how should I do?

```
public PartialViewResult searchList()
        {
            var model = db.search.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.date).ToList();
            return PartialView("~/Areas/admin/Views/Shared/Layout/_search.cshtml", model);
        }
```

Comment: do you want the list of the incoming request to the action "searchList()" or you are talking about the var model that you created in your method ?

Comment: What do you mean, "It doesn't work"?  If you were to set a breakpoint, do you get any values back from the call to the database? Does that view (`_search.cshtml`) accept a model of that type?  We're missing that partial, a minimal reproducible example that shows us where your problem lies (for instance, we cannot currently replicate your database, and we shouldn't need to -- if you change your example to put a dummy-list with objects and data together and show us that, we could see where the problem lies.

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Comment: I want him to add the same words to the list once.

Comment: Is words a property of search object?

Comment: as you can see , same words that searched in website repeats itself, i want to see these same words in same column .https://ibb.co/cDfWPnT for example dental searched 8 times but i see this data more than once

Comment: as you can see , same words that searched in website repeats itself, i want to see these same words in same column .ibb.co/cDfWPnT for example dental searched 8 times but i see this data more than once

Comment: distinct() operates on the whole selection, not just one field. It doesn't know which field you intended to be distinct, so it looks across the whole row to find ones where all the columns have identical values. That's true of SQL as well not just linq. If you want it to work with Distinct you may want to try selecting only the column containing the word first, before you apply the distinct().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the `IEquatable<T>` if you want to return distinct elements from sequences of objects of some **custom data type** or by using a specified `IEqualityComparer<T>` to compare values

Read documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8)

OR

Simply group them and pick the first one. Example below groups by `SearchId` and picks the first one

```
List<Search> distinctSearch = db.Search
  .GroupBy(s => s.SearchId) 
  .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: as you can see , same words that searched in website repeats itself, i want to see these same words in same column .https://ibb.co/cDfWPnT for example dental searched 4 times but i see this data more than once

Comment: Can you post your data to this question? The List of search that is